# 2D Colliders collisions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider

I have a problem with physics. I'm trying to do something and I do not know if this is possible in Unity2D.

[image: Example image]

In the picture you see what I want to do. I want that circle to get into that cone.
The problem is that if I put in a collider circle it collides with the cone. That's why I wonder if there is any way to do this without 3D elements.

Comment: In 2D, shouldn't just the circles edges (left and right) collide?

Comment: something like that

Comment: to try to put the left and right edge collider?

Comment: Yes, you should try that. I'd use two Circle Colliders on the edges. Also you should split the circle in a foreground and a background layer.

Comment: it looks like it works